# Need to resize image for imageview

Tags: android, image, imageview, bitmapfactory

I have an image that is 8 mp but it can't be displayed on an ImageView because it is too large of a file. How can I re-size it with a BitmapFactory and then pass this new image as the source of ImageView in the XML?

my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/select"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Select" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Info" />

</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/test_image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ImageView view;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize=8; //also tried 32, 64, 16
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher, options);
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bmp);

    view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.test_image_view);
    view.setImageDrawable(d);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);


}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't pass it into XML**

For what? Load it, when you need it.
In your case it's better to use BitmapFactory.Options:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize=16; //image will be 16x smaller than an original. Note, that it's better for perfomanse to use powers of 2 (2,4,8,16,32..).
Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeSomething(..., options) //use any decode method instead of this
Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(bmp);
```

and then just set it to your `ImageView`

```
ImageView iv; //initialize it first, of course. For example, using findViewById.
iv.setImageDrawable(d);
```

Note, that you should recycle your bitmap, after you used it (after ImageView is not visible anymore):

```
bmp.recycle();
```

Comment: it still crashes, i'm posting my code, could you take a quick look at it?

Comment: @Aneem first of all - you don't setted your options in `decodeResource` method (it should be a last parameter). Second - maybe value `16` is not what are you're looking for (also you can try 32, 64 etc.)

Comment: @Aneem oh, I got it, sorry :) Main problem is that you should write your `setContentView` right after `super.onCreate()`. Otherwise your UI will not work.

Comment: WOW, it works now! Thanks so much biovamp, you've been amazing!

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that you can programmatically resize the image and then use it in XML. Everything in your XML file is pretty much static and read at compile time, so there is no going back to it.
You'll to use the BitmapFactory and then set the image both in java.

Comment: Then please select it as an answer :)

Comment: PS. I've ran into this issue with strings a bunch of times and that was the conclusion I came to.

Comment: i will, i cant now though, its saying that i can accept an answer in 3 minutes